Hide taskbar on specific desktop
I am using Windows 10 but this question can probably apply to other versions of Windows.
I want to open multiple desktops in windows and swap between them using the WIN+TAB shortcut. I don't always need a taskbar on some desktops, so why not disable it on certain desktops?
I don't see an option to do that in the built-in Windows settings. I downloaded TransluscentTB, don't see any option for handling different desktops.
Took a look at ButteryTaskbar 2 but it's written in Jai. That is a closed beta language at the moment, so I can't modify it's source code to do what I want (although given the similarity to C I can guess, ultimately it calls the Windows APIs anyway).
I vaguely recall using some software that could manage the Windows virtual desktops, before, although maybe it couldn't hide the taskbar, but I no longer remember it. What I essentially need to do is:

Identify the current desktop ID. This is trivial if I can find a few lines of code to do it.
Hide the taskbar on a per desktop ID basis. Non-trivial, it depends on how the taskbar works, I don't know if it's even aware of different desktops beyond "This is desktop 0 and that isn't desktop 0".

I'll try to look on MDN later but I don't really want to do this if someone has a working solution

Native Windows 8+ will allow you to extend the taskbar to other displays or not, but that means you either have the taskbar on the primary monitor, but not the rest, or on all, although not sure if this still is a thing in windows 11. You can make any monitor your primary to select which monitor gets the taskbar though...

I'm asking about desktops, not displays. And yes, that is still a thing in Windows 10

Ah, you are talking about a virtual desktop and want the taskbar to be gone there. Hmm, tough one. Don't even know any of the popular virtual desktops that allow you to hide/show the taskbar. But if there's one program that can, then it must be ActualTools Window Manager
